# When developing plugins where should you store values that might not strictly be settings?

Tags: plugin-development

For instance I'm writing a plugin which is going to be periodically pulling stuff from Twitter, so I'd like to keep a hold of when the plugin was last run and maybe some Ids relevant to Twitter that sort of thing.

I know there is the settings array which you use for user defined values, should I also use it for other stuff that the user can't change, or is there a more sensible place to stick those?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a [Record](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/records) which will give you a custom table to store your twitter related settings and update them as needed but I think that your use case is still simple enough that you could leave them in the `settings array` and then use the `Plugins Service` to update those settings.

This is how I would do it if I chose to use `defineSettings()`

---

```php
// MyPlugin.php
public function defineSettings()
{
   return array(
        // ...
        'twitterApiKey' => array(AttributeType::String, 'default' => '5omeRand0mstriNg'),
        'twitterUsername' => array(AttributeType::String, 'default' => 'someone'),
    );
}
```

```php
// MyService.php
public function saveTwitterSettings(array $settings=array())
{
    $plugin = craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myplugin');
    $savedSettings = $plugin->getSettings()->getAttributes();
    $newSettingsRow = array_merge($savedSettings, $settings);

    return craft()->plugins->savePluginSettings($plugin, $newSettingsRow);
}
```

---

Feel free to follow up with questions/comments if you have any.

[@selvinortiz](http://twitter.com/selvinortiz)

Comment: Thanks Selvin, Records was the piece of the puzzle I was missing. I do also want to keep a log of each run of the plugin, so I think in this instance a Record may make more sense. Your code will come in handy next time for instances where a Record is a little too much.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to the docs for the record @Steve and yes, in that case you'll definitely need one. Craft makes it a joy to interact with the database via records and the query builder: )