# How can I create global code variables?

Tags: templating

I'm wondering if there's any equivalent to the Yii "params" array I can set on Twig code template level for re-use throughout all my templates using Twig syntax?

Comment: You could make your own var with a plugin, but you're looking for a native solution, right?

Comment: Yeah if there is any. Otherwise I'll go that route or just stick with Globals. But something native would be nice (if possible) from the configuration files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Besides saving the variable in a field (e.g. global set) you could also add a ["Environment Variable"](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#environmentVariables) to
your general.php file:

`'myGlobalVariable' => 'I am available in all environments'`

but you can **only access it** from Twig, it's not possible to update it:

`{{ craft.config.myGlobalVariable }}`

If you do need to **update from  your Twig templates**, you should make a custom plugin / add to your Business Logic plugin.
There's various options to make a variable available in your Twig templates:

- add a ["Template Variable"](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) to the `{{ craft }}` global variable

or with a Twig Extention:

- add a new [Global Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables) using [`getGlobals()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/templating/twigextensions/CraftTwigExtension#getGlobals-detail)
- add a [Twig function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions) with `new Twig_SimpleFunction()`

With a plugin you have these options to save your value (and update with a custom Twig function):

- in a [Record](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/records), update with `$record->save()`
- directly in the plugin settings, update with `craft()->plugins->savePluginSettings()` (→ [read more on SE](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/338/125))
- with a config.php file in the plugin folder, not possible to update with Twig (→ [read more on SE](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2000/125))
- hard code it into the plugin PHP ;)

Comment: Rock solid answer - as usual! Thank you sir!