# Is it possible to extend twig with 'Twig_SimpleTest'?

Tags: plugin-development, twigextension

I was on the Twig StackExchange forum and found [**an answer that suited my needs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876023/check-if-variable-is-string-or-array-in-twig#answer-29642662).

But I can't for the life of me figure out how to implement this into a Craft CMS Plugin.

I'm familiar with `Twig_Function_Method` and `Twig_Filter_Method`, but I can't find anything on `Twig_SimpleTest`.

Has the option to include "tests" been omitted from Craft CMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call Craft's [TemplatesService->getTwig()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#getTwig-detail) (`craft()->templates->getTwig()`), you get an instance of the Twig environment and from there you could be able to call [`addTest`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#tests).

100% untested, but something like this should work:

```
$twig = craft()->templates->getTwig();
$twig->addTest(new My_Twig_SimpleTest());
```

Comment: Note that if you want to get back the same Twig environment instance that Craft is actually using to render templates, there are some caveats, outlined [here](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/16492/1098).

Comment: Thanks Mats Mikkel Rummelhoff (again). Those caveats were a response to one of my previous questions :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Brad, that's what I was after. In the case of what I was trying to achieve; the following in my plugins init function did the job:

```
$twig = craft()->templates->getTwig();

$twig->addTest(new \Twig_SimpleTest('array', function ($value) {
  return is_array($value);
}));
```

I always struggle with syntax, so hopefully this example will help others.

---

**Craft 3 Solution**:

Add this to your plugins main init() function:

```
$this->addTests(Craft::$app->view->getTwig());
```

Then add this function after the init():

```
private function addTests($twig) {
  // Is String
  $twig->addTest(new \Twig_SimpleTest('string', function ($value) {
    return is_string($value);
  }));
}
```