# Defining TwigExtension globals in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, globals

A long time ago [I asked how I could utilise the getGlobal method in Craft 2.x](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16491/does-twigs-addglobal-exist-in-craft).

I'd like to know how best to do this in Craft 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

**Option 1**

Add this in your plugin/module main init function:

```
      $twig = Craft::$app->view->getTwig(null, ['safe_mode' => false]);
      $twig->addGlobal('foo', 'bar');
```

That's it. You can call 'foo' in your template like this `{{ foo }} // Output 'bar'`

**Option 2 (best)**

In the root of your plugin/module directory, create a folder called 'twigextensions' if you don't already have one. Create a new file where you're going to define your globals. `MyGlobals.php` for example.

At the very top of your main plugin/module file, you need to add this:

```
use modules\myawesomemodile\twigextensions\MyGlobals;
```

... remembering to amend the plugin/module name, and the name of the file you created.

Then add the following to the same file. Only this needs to be inside your main init function:

```
Craft::$app->view->registerTwigExtension(new MyGlobals());
```

Lastly, in your new MyGlobals.php file. Add the following. Again changning the plugin/module names where appropriate.

```
namespace modules\myawesomemodule\twigextensions;

use modules\myawesomemodule\MyAwesomeModule;

use Craft;

class MyGlobals extends \Twig_Extension implements \Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface
{

    public function getGlobals()
    {
        return array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
        );
    }
}
```

That's it. Like before, you can call 'foo' in your template like this `{{ foo }} // Output 'bar'`

Now I don't understand the technical reasons as to why one is better than the other. I prefer **Option 2** because it permits me to add multiple globals. However, my old post was answered by [Mats Mikkel Rummelhoff](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/users/1098/mats-mikkel-rummelhoff); who goes into this in a [little more detail](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16491/does-twigs-addglobal-exist-in-craft#answer-16492).